# In Hadoop HDFS, delete several files older than x days and with spaces in the name (Not like UNIX)

Tags: hadoop, awk, hdfs, cloudera

I have hundreds of thousands of files in a hadoop directory and I need to debug them. I'm looking to delete files that are more than 3 months old and I'm trying to delete in batches of a thousand files that I get in that directory with that condition, but I'm having problems. Among the multitude of files there are files that have some space in the name, like "hello word.csv". I've tried doing the batches, using arrays in unix or writing the output to a file, but one way or another, it doesn't recognise the files in when doing **hdfs dfs -rm -f**

With this, i found that files

```
list_files=$(hdfs dfs -ls "${folder_in}" | awk '!/^d/ {print $0}' | awk -v days=${dias} '!/^d/ && $6 < strftime("%Y-%m-%d", systime() - days * 24 * 60 * 60) { print substr($0, index($0,$8)) }')
```

I wanted to delete the HDFS files in batches by loading an array in the shellscript as follows:

```
while IFS="" read -r file; do
    files+=(\"${file}\")
    echo -e "\"$file\"" > ${PATH_TMP}/file_del_proof.tmp
done <<< "$list_files"
```

With the following script I tried to delete the HDFS files:

```
    total_lines=$(wc -l < "${PATH_TMP}/file_del_proof.tmp")
    start_line=1
    while [ $start_line -le $total_lines ]; do
        end_line=$((start_line + batch_size - 1))
        end_line=$((end_line > total_lines ? total_lines : end_line))
        hdfs dfs -rm -f -skipTrash $(awk -v end_line=${end_line} -v start_line=${start_line} 'NR >= start_line && NR <= end_line' "${PATH_TMP}/file_del_proof.tmp")
        start_line=$((end_line + 1))
   done
```

The problem is that in that list appear some files that have spaces in the name, I can not find an automatic way to delete those files with more than a certain time in the HDFS because some come with spaces in the name and when deleting, for example if the files are called "hello word.csv", "hello word2.csv", "hello word2.csv", it only interprets the hello remaining for one line.

```
hdfs dfs -rm /folder/hello
```

One person gave me the idea to delete the 3 oldest months, first move the 3 most recent months to a temporary folder, delete everything left in the folder and then move from that temporary folder to the original one. But still if I want to move those with space names, I fail that mv because the files with spaces, are not moved.

Does anyone have any suggestions?
The idea I was given was to replace the spaces in the hdfs with _ in the files that had that particularity, but I wanted to see if anyone knew of any other option to delete them without doing that preprocessing of changing the name.

Comment: @Fravadona That should work... I've not tested recently

Comment: Think I mentioned this before - Why not use Java Hadoop Filesytem API instead of bash? Then you have actual `Path` objects to delete, not "strings with spaces"

Comment: Hello OneCricketerr. Thank you very much for your suggestion. I really wanted to see how to apply it because I have never worked with Java Hadoop Filesytem API. I looked for some example code but I had no idea how to launch that script or from where. It would be interesting to see how this api works.

Comment: _no idea how to launch that script_ - You would install Java (as you would need to on Hadoop server anyway), then execute `java -jar cleaner-script.jar` with the compiled code... You could run it in Oozie, as one example, on a schedule, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It feels like using `hdfs dfs -stat` instead of `hdfs dfs -ls` would be a better choice; example:

```bash
$ hdfs dfs -stat '%Y,%F,%n/' some/dir/*
1391807842598,regular file,hello world.csv/
1388041686026,directory,someDir/
1388041686026,directory,otherDir/
1391807875417,regular file,File2.txt/
1391807842724,regular file,File one, two, three!.txt/
```

**remark:** I added a trailing `/` to the output format so that `awk` can use it as record separator (it's a character that can't appear in a filename). Also, using a `,` as field separator allows to accurately get the first two fields (the filename might have commas in it but you can just strip the first two fields from the record).

Now, all that's left to do is to select the files whose "modification time" is smaller than the `time-of-day - N days`, rebuild their full path and output the latter as a `NUL`-delimited list for `xargs -0` to process:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

folder_in=some/path
dias=30

printf '%s\0' "$folder_in"/* |
xargs -0 hdfs dfs -stat '%Y,%F,%n/' |
awk -v days="$dias" '
    BEGIN {
        RS = "/";
        basepath = ARGV[1];
        delete ARGV[1];
        srand();
        modtime = (srand() - days * 86400) * 1000
    }
    $2 == "regular file" && $1 < modtime {
        sub(/^([^,]*,){2}/,"");
        printf("%s%c", basepath "/" $0, 0)
    }
' "$folder_in" |
xargs -0 hdfs dfs -rm -f
```

**notes:**

- Because you're dealing with "*hundreds of thousands of files*" I'm using the bash builtin `printf` for expanding the `*` glob. FYI, any non-builtin command would fail with an `Argument list too long` error.
- As a consequence of using `/` as record separator in `awk`, each `$1` have a leading `\n` character; it doesn't matter because `$1` is used as a number so the newline is implicitly ignored. Additionally, the last record will be a single `\n` character, which is filtered out by the `$2 == "regular file"` condition.

Comment: Great Fravadona, thank you very much, we saved the homeland :D The script worked great for an initial test I did on a small folder. I only had to make a couple of adjustments.
1.- Instead of srand I used modtime = strftime("%s")*1000 - days * 86400. I had to multiply it by 1000 because unix didn't add the milliseconds
2.-Here I had to add column 3 instead of column 2 
$3 == "file" && $1 < modtime {
        sub(/^([^ ]* ){3}/,"");
        printf("%s%c", basepath "/" $0, 0)
    }
since the stat returned
1684169209377 regular file OBArgentina_BundleUserStatus_2021-02-27_000000-235959.csv

Comment: @alejomarchan My bad, there were indeed some problems with the code; I fixed them. BTW, `strftime` and `systime` are specific to GNU awk while `srand(); srand()` is 100% portable.

Comment: I am totally grateful to you Fravadona. There I tried with the date and it was great, then I understood your concept of it being portable. The change %Y,%F,%n/ to separate by commas, I will do it in an update to test it directly in production :D